# Strategies to do an accurate CR estimation with a special customer

Tags: scope, change-management, analysis

What strategies can I employ to conduct thorough pre-analysis and estimation for change requests (CR) in a project when we lack system access and rely solely on customer-provided requirements? We often find that relying solely on customer requirements leads to scope discrepancies, making negotiations for additional work challenging.

Two ideas we're considering are:

1. Issuing a new CR if we identify additional scope during analysis that cannot be absorbed within the original CR. (Note: This may encounter resistance from the customer.)
2. Planning an out-of-the-CR pre-analysis session, involving a time-fixed on-site visit to understand requirements more thoroughly before generating the CR document. (Note: This approach may incur additional costs and may not be well-received by the customer.)

What other ideas or strategies could help ensure accurate pre-analysis and estimation in such scenarios?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The scenario you provided, where there's a lot of uncertainty around requirements, is the reason why there's agile and [adaptative project life cycles](https://pm.stackexchange.com/a/31347/430).

Being over simplistic, the strategy you should consider is to focus to deliver the smallest piece of deliverable you have confidence about. Once you deliver this, you validate that's what users were expecting, rinse and repeat.

Comment: Agree. But unfortunately my company isn't providing agile methodology. So I am stuck with traditional approach